# Get height/width of SVG <img> in Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, svg, cross-browser

I'm attempting to get the height/width of an SVG  element created in JS using `image.width` and `image.height`.

On Chrome (latest), this returns a width and height with both base64 encoded SVGs and data URIs are the `image.src`.

However, on Firefox (latest), these are both returning `0`,even if I set up an `image.onload` listener.

#### Example

```
// base64 encoded SVG - EXPECTED 250x150
const base64String = new Image();
base64String.src = "data:image/svg+xml;base64,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";

base64String.onload = function() {
  console.log(base64String.width, base64String.height); // Returns 250 150 on Chrome, 0 0 on FF
};
```

[here's a JSBin](https://jsbin.com/kuzovihumo/edit?js,console) showing the problem. Open it in both Chrome and FF to see the different outputs. There's a .jpg in there as a control too which works in both.

Comment: Please add the relevant parts of your code to the question

Comment: your base64 encoded svg image data does not have height and width attributes on its root <svg> element so there is no height and width to report. What's your definition of "Chrome works correctly"? Why do you think it should report non-zero values since there's nothing viable to use as values.

Comment: No idea what Chrome's reporting, seems like a Chrome bug.

Comment: @RobertLongson - I've changed the wording to remove the opinion that Chrome is correct. It turns out each browser handles having no height/width differently, but Firefox was where the errors were being caught as this was used in a division.

Answer (score 2):

After some research it appears that browsers give SVGs without dimensions some defaults whilst preserving the aspect ratio, Chrome's being 350x150. Firefox returns 0 for these values instead. [source](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/)